# Правовые и юридические вопросы, связанные с программированием

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, закрытие-вопросов

Увидел, что закрыт данный вопрос:

- [Использовать чужие картинки из интернета в приложении android?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/515175/199934)

Основываясь на [прецеденте](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/enc_law/81/%D0%90%D0%9D%D0%93%D0%9B%D0%9E%D0%A1%D0%90%D0%9A%D0%A1%D0%9E%D0%9D%D0%A1%D0%9A%D0%90%D0%AF), пометил тревогой вопрос, закрытый уже другим модератором:

- [Нарушаю ли авторские права?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/517538/199934)

Впоследствии после моей тревоги был объявлен требующим правки ещё и этот:

- [Правовые аспекты работы с чужим API](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/349676/199934)

Т. к. закрытие поддержали уже 2 разных модератора, расставил тревоги в 10 других вопросах, примеры:

- [Авторское право в программировании (Интеллектуальная собственность)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/60605/199934),
- [Xamarin Forms - пара вопросов про лицензию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/448363/199934),
- [Лицензия на иконку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/177362/199934).

Тревоги были [отклонены](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/199934), а я [забанен](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2973/199934). В качестве причины отклонения приводилась ссылка на [следующее обсуждение](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1234/199934).

Вижу 3 варианта разрешения:

1. Следовать [ответу Nick Volynkin](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1236/199934) и переоткрыть первые 3 вопроса.
2. Продолжать объявлять «требующими правки» правовые и юридические вопросы, следовательно, закрыть примеры 4—6 данного сообщения.
3. Чётче прописать, что можно, а какие нельзя.

Сохранение status quo считаю субъективизмом, а потому неприемлемым.

Comment: Не уловил: вы открывать или закрывать тревожили? И список ваших тревог доступен только вам и модераторам. Если хотите поделиться его содержимым, то можете сделать скриншот.

Comment: @Discord, закрывать. Про доступ понял. Большую часть вопросов привёл, думаю, скриншот покажется излишним. Спасибо.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Я за то, чтобы переоткрыть все.

Comment: Очень радует возможность поставить зеленую галку на тот ответ, который понравился топикастеру. А не на тот, за который проголосовали участники. @СашаЧерных, вы же понимаете, что применятся будет решение из ответа с наибольшим количеством голосов? А не из того, на который вы галку поставили :)

Comment: @PashaPash ох уж эта зеленая галка.

Comment: Как минимум - привести к общему знаменателю такие вопросы. Из всех предложенных вижу 2 метки: `авторство` и `лицензирование`, но так же вижу, что метки есть не везде. Ну давайте еще прицепим `хакинг` или его аналог к неугодным. Знать о последствиях конечно должны все, и это знание вовсе не означает призыв к действию. То же самое касается вопросов безопасности, наоборот: пусть выкладывают как можно больше таких `хаков` и все, кто защищает свои права будут как минимум готовы к ним. По моему, это очень важно! +1

Answer (score 16):

Лицензии на ПО и их применение имеют прямое отношение к программированию. Но факты их нарушения - скорее всего нет.

Аналогия из жизни:

- соблюдение скоростного режима имеют прямое отношение к вождению машины.
- попытка уговорить инспектора на взятку за превышение скорости - не имеет отношения ни к вождению, ни к соблюдению правил.

Я бы предложил разделить вопросы на хорошие вопросы по лицензиям и плохие - по их нарушению.

Хорошие, которые топикастер задает ради соблюдения лицензий:

- [Лицензия GNU AGPLv3 и play market](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/367906/)
- [В чем разница между коммерческой и свободно распостроняемой лицензией для QT фреймворка?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/200837/)
- [Разработка на заказ с использованием GPL](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/385654/)
- [Использую в игре бесплатные изображения. Как не быть забаненым на GP?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/493829/)
- [Лицензия на иконку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/177362/)
- [Xamarin Forms - пара вопросов про лицензию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/448363/)
- [Авторское право в программировании (Интеллектуальная собственность)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/60605/)

Плохие, в которых топикастер прямо заявляет о нарушении лицензии и спрашивает "а что мне будет?":

- [Использовать чужие картинки из интернета в приложении android?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/515175/)
- [Правовые аспекты работы с чужим API](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/349676/) - стоило бы спросить автора API, а не сообщество SO
- [Нарушаю ли авторские права?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/517538/) (под сомнением)

Хорошие - оставить. Плохие - закрыть.

Все мы пишем софт, все представляем количество труда, которое нужно вложить в -создание чего-то стоящего. Все мы, прямо или косвенно, заинтересованы в том, чтобы лицензии соблюдались (как нами, так и теми, кто будет пользоваться результатами нашего труда). Нарушение лицензии в любом более-менее крупном проекте - это проблема похуже исчезновения leftpad.

Представьте, что вы видите вопрос "Я украл чужие исходники, поменял в них название продукта, и продаю как свое. Что мне будет?". Посчитали бы вы такой вопрос допустимым? Если нет - то почему считаются допустимыми вопросы про кражу картинок?

Comment: А что, я почитал бы ответ на это от хорошего юриста: «согласно статье такой-то такого-то кодекса, вам светит от 5 до 7 лет» :) Но юридические советы на SO — абсурд, т. к. [почти] никто из нас не юрист.

Comment: А как же [итоги опроса](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/2869/199934), где большинство высказалось за допустимость «вопросов, затрагивающих этику, правонарушения и интересы третьих лиц»? Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных Тот опрос касался *технических* вопросов с сомнительным подтекстом. Он не превращает вопросы "как мне избежать наказания за грабеж" в онтопик. Сомнительные технические вопросы - ок. Несомнительные вопросы по лицензии - ок. Сомнительные нетехнические вопросы - в топку.

Comment: PashaPash, я перечитал текст опроса — не нашёл в нём уточнения про «технические». Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных там обсуждались онтопичные вопросы с сомнительным подтекстом. И суть голосования была - делает ли сомнительный подтекст такие вопросы оффтопиком. Решили что не делает. Это не значит, что теперь вообще любые вопросы с сомнительным подтекстом стали оффтопиком.

Comment: с точки зрения высшего блага вопросы можно поделить на хорошие или плохие, но с точки зрения SO они плохие все, поскольку ответы на них будут состоять в основном из "я не юрист", общих рассуждений без ссылок на законы (какой страны), цитат из FAQ лицензии (непонятно насколько стыкующихся с местным законодательством) и личного опыта (который не является очевидно верным). При этом в случае очевидности нарушения лицензии "плохие" вопросы лучше "хороших". Поэтому я считаю, что надо если включать в онтопик, то все, игнорируя моральную сторону, поскольку на сайте и так пастбище хромых HelloWorld'ов.

Comment: @zRrr пересмотрел все условно хорошие вопросы, ни нашел ни одного "я не юрист". Хостеры и маркетплейсы реагируют на любой abuse очень быстро, неважно насколько это стыкуется с местным законодательством. Т.е. всем все равно на нарушение лицензии на винду на домашнем компе (и это оффтопик). Но всем не все равно на нарушение лицензии на код. Это, практически, смерть для продукта.

Comment: @zRrr и да, я не юрист, но вопросы "как мне пользоваться крякнутым zzz, чтобы никто не заметил" прямо нарушают http://stackexchange.com/legal: infringes, violates or otherwise interferes with any copyright or trademark of another party. Т.е. формулировка настолько общая, что малейшего намека на нарушение копирайта (в широком его смысле) вообще в любом виде достаточно для сноса вопроса.

Comment: @PashaPash процитированный вами кусок ToS - это часть пункта о том, что участник обещает не приносить на сайт копирайченый контент (но я тоже не юрист), а еще коммерческую тайну и фото людей, поскольку все, что публикуется на сайте автоматически лицензируется под cc-by-sa. Лучше бы подошел пункт 4, который запрещает использовать Сеть для illegal activity. Но это все из разряда "администрация сети имеет право снести почти любой пост, чтобы не иметь проблем"

Comment: @PashaPash теперь давайте посмотрим на ваши "плохие" вопросы. Ни в одном из них нет "как мне нарушить, чтобы не поймали". Первый вопрос это "нарушаю ли я, если моя программа скачивает и показывает копирайченую картинку из интернетов", второй: "можно ли пользоваться чужим непубличным апи без разрешения", третий: "моя программа использует чужой опубликованный контент, владелец контента обещает нажаловаться в гугль, он правда так может?". Чем они хуже "я хочу использовать чужую иконку" и "может ли заказчик не отдавать исходники вместе с программой, использующей библиотеку GPL" не совсем понятно.

Comment: очевидно, что пример действительно плохого вопроса ("дайте кряк на идею ультимате") с сайта привести нельзя, поскольку он не закрывается, а просто сносится.

Comment: @zRrr вопрос про иконку - человек честно спросил "можно ли". ему вполне честно ответили "по лицензии на сайте - нельзя". Никто ничего не нарушал. В вопросе про GPL - то же самое. В них нет даже намека на нарушение лицензии. Даже наоборот - они заданы чтобы лицензию не нарушить. Вопросы из плохих - программа уже использует чужой контент с нарушением копирайта, владелец уже нажаловался. Картинка уже закопирайчена, топикастер уже понимает что ее использовать нельзя, но ищет пути это "обойти". Т.е. они направлены прежде всего на нарушение лицензии. И этим они хуже (illegal activity в чистом виде).

Comment: @zRrr а вопрос про апи - зависит от апи. стоит закрыть как "необходимо уточнить подробности".

Comment: @PashaPash т.е. если я сейчас перепишу текст вопроса,использовав будущее время, или даже в форме "могу ли я", то вопрос станет хорошим? Мне не нравится такой подход. Во-первых, я не знаю, как это сформулировать в [help/on-topic], во-вторых ответы для любой формы вопроса будут одинаковые.

Comment: @zRrr причем тут будущее время? я предложил разделить по намерениям топикастера. Если намерение - соблюсти лицензию - оставить. Если явно высказано намерение нарушить лицензию (т.е. нет  даже намека на попытки ее соблюсти) - снести. "могу ли я взять такую-то картинку" допустимый вопрос - на него можно однозначно ответить, все счастливы. "я взял картинку, как мне ее подфотошопить чтоб не спалили" - плохой вопрос. Не вижу причин как-то дополнительно формулировать это в справке - оно и так сформулировано в legal и в двух топиках на мете.