# О недружественности руcскоязычного StackOverflow

Tags: обсуждение

Сайт **StackOverflow на русском** мне показался реально не дружелюбным и не дружественным сайтом. Я сюда пишу все реже и реже.

Мне здесь закрывают вопросы, которые на англоязычном SO активно и с пользой для всех обсуждаются и люди **радуются** поиску решения... (Это к слову)

И так, сайт **stackoverflow на русском** просит задавать вопросы! **"Не бойся, задавай!"**

Вот, например, задаю...

[Вот вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/787556/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B3-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%83-%D0%B2-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5-google-adwords)

Задаю по **активному (работающему) тегу**, **существующему на сайте**! И что из этого получилось.. Вопрос из реальной практики программиста. Нашел ответ (обратился в поддержку Google)... Поделился ответом. Еще и Гуглу такое полезно пообсуждать... )

> Объявлен 2 дня назад требующим правки участниками A K, 0xdb, Viktor
>   Tomilov, Eugene Krivenja, iluxa1810, так как **непонятна суть
>   вопроса**.
>   **Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что
>   вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример, наглядно
>   демонстрирующий проблему.**

**Все сделал как рекомендовали - еще хуже стало - стали начислять отрицательные баллы!!!**

Раньше вопросы называли **не полезными**, сейчас **не понятными**. Но суть не меняется...

**Закрывают вопросы по одной причине, потом объясняют другую и от злобы еще и минусы минусуют!**

Уберите теги по которым нельзя писать!...

Сайт просит задавать вопросы, а потом унижают задавших!

Создается впечатление, что продвинувшиеся заинтересованы принижать начинающих!
Хочу верить, что таких мало! )

P.S. Кстати, за то, что я поднял этот вопрос меня реально похвалили в Google (улыбка), потому что такой важный показатель как **Остаток денежных средств** на счете клиента должен быть, буквально, на самом видном месте (либо настраиваемом месте)

Поживем-увидим... )

Comment: *за то, что я поднял этот вопрос меня реально похвалили в Google (улыбка)* - конечно, т.к. это их продукт, а Вы клиент. Значимость вопроса компании по ее продукту отличается от значимости вопроса не по теме в сообществе определенной тематики. Ваш вопрос вероятно важен для многих людей, но в данном сообществе рассматриваются вопросы по тематике сообщества. по поводу дружелюбия - у каждого свои рамки, но Вас не оскорбили, не заминусовали, только закрыли вопрос как не по теме и только.

Comment: @user я уже прямо написал вам под вопросом - если вы считаете, что стоит включить "видеть вопросы, решаемые программистами, шире чем просто код" ... и даже вопросы решаемые не программистами, и даже вообще не про IT -  оформите это в виде отдельного обсуждения не мете. Или хотя бы прочтите ответы на этот ваш вопрос на мете, вместо того, чтобы добавлять к вопросу не имеющие никакого отношения к нему метки.

Comment: @user я к тому, что есть ровно один способ расширения онтопика - через обсуждение на мете. Сообщество тут *дружелюбное*, но даже с таким запасом дружелюбия мелкие несущественные правки вопроса, игнорирование прямого указания на оффтопик, переход на личности, и прочие попытки привлечь внимание к вопросу ни к чему хорошему не приведут. Вам предложили прямой способ решения проблемы. Воспользуйтесь им, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я поддерживаю автора вопроса. Онтопик конечно очень важная тема.

Но со стороны того кто задаёт вопрос реально **очень неприятно** когда вопрос закрывают и минусуют.

Реально желание заходить на сайт у многих после этого может пропадать, в том числе и у меня.

Когда задаю вопрос который чуть-чуть не по тематике трясусь что его закроют или заминусуют.

Кстати я стал замечать что это стало как **фанатизм, изжигание неправомерных вопросов**... Можно же более спокойно относиться, человек пишет такой вопрос не по причине того что хочет сайту навредить. Более того раньше такого **правило-фанатизма** было значительно меньше.

Comment: Прикол в том, что это не так. Никакого фанатизма в отношении пограничных вопросов нет. Откройте глаза, ваш вопрос про банковские карты был заплюсован до небес. Минусуются наоборот вопросы по программированию, которые кто-то посчитал "ленивыми" или тупо не понимает суть SO, вот что плохо.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight >>или тупо не понимает суть SO, вот что плохо<< да, я это и имел ввиду, не соответствуешь правилам идёшь в топку. Конечно я тут пишу крайние случае, и в целом есть разные ситуации и моменты. Но всё же я вижу в некоторых ситуациях фанатичность. Я сам несколько раз отшивал вопросы которые по моему мнение не соответствовали тематике сайта. И заметил что это как такая программа в подсознании, что-то типа дедовщины. Конечно это не везде и не всегда есть. Лично мне такие программы не нужны, и со своей стороны я пересмотрел жёсткое отрезание вопросов.

Comment: Я имею ввиду где-то механистичный подход, алгоримичный `if(Не соответсвие правилам или теме) break user;`. Это не нравится. Потому что каждый человек он человек, и какие бы правила не были, я думаю более важно что бы он получал радость и удовлетворение от общения на сайте, а не соблюдения формальных стандартов. Всё же надо чувствовать когда отвечаешь человеку, что ты ему своим ответом, действием дашь, и какова будет его реакция... Возможно он просто после ответа уйдёт с сайта.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight и спасибо вам за пример принятие ответа даже без согласия с ним (я так почувствовал), а не закидывания помидорами, как иногда бывает.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight почитал ваш комментарий ещё раз. Про реакцию пользователей, да вы всё верно написали, такие вопросы часто даже хорошо плюсуются как мой вопрос про банковские карточки. Но потом приходит модератор или другие пользователи с правом голосовать за закрытие и делают это.

Comment: Ваш вопрос сообщество наоборот пыталось переоткрывать. Закрыто оно было лишь потому, что вы привлекли внимание Николаса на мете. К слову, он довольно четко обосновал, что не так с вопросом и почему он закрыт. О каком-то произволе речи нет.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight переоткрыли а Николас опять закрыл... Насчёт  его обоснования я не согласен, но честно говоря не хочется на обсуждение этой темы тратить своё время, а то получится что вопрос у меня занял 20 минут условно, а обоснование его нужности и защиты его (ито без гарантии что получится защитить и обосновать) тратить часы времени и нервы.

Comment: Лично я предлагаю расширите онтопик сайта до всего IT и подобные непонятные и где-то обидные или унизительные ситуации просто перестанут быть.

Answer (score 16):

#### Почему ваш вопрос был закрыт первый раз

> Непонятна суть вопроса. Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, **что вы хотите получить в результате** и т. д. Приведите пример, наглядно демонстрирующий проблему.

Из изначальной формулировки не было понятно, хотите ли вы получить остаток на счету кодом (через api), или через интерфейс пользователя. Согласитесь, это достаточно разные вещи.

Т.е. непонятно было, ждете вы ответа в виде инструкций для пользователя или в виде кода. [Об этом вам, кстати, явно написали в комментариях](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/787556/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b3-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%83-%d0%b2-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b5-google-adwords#comment1239210_787556).

#### Почему ваш вопрос был закрыт во второй раз

> Скорее всего, данный вопрос не соответствует тематике Stack Overflow на русском, согласно правилам описанным в [справке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help).

На сайте есть достаточно [жесткий онтопик](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Допустимы только вопросы, напряму касающиеся программирования, администрирования или каких-то специфических для IT проблем. Об этом прямо сказано в справке:

> Вопросы по теме, которые тем не менее **не стоит задавать**:
>
> - Вопросы, касающиеся использования программного обеспечения, если они не относятся к программированию или системному администрированию.

Google AdWords - это инструмент маркетологов, он не имеет никакого отношения ни к программированию, ни к системному администрированию. Вопрос закрыли не потому, что он плохой или неинтересный. Просто он не имеет никакого отношения к онтопику.

#### Почему на сайте есть теги, по которым "нельзя писать"?

Дело в том, что у Google AdWords есть API. И вопросы по этому API вполне допустимы. Например:

[BudgetOrderService getBillingAccounts вовзвращает null](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/723996/)

Несмотря на странный заголовок, это вопрос именно о получении текущего остатка на счете через API. Т.е. задавать вопросы на тему AdWords можно, но только до тех пор, пока они соответствуют общей тематике сайта.

#### Унижают задавших, на enSO лучше

В комментариях вам достаточно вежливо объяснили причину закрытия вопроса. Причем сделали это четыре разных участника. Вопрос не удалили, даже сильно не заминусовали (вы на нем получили намного больше репутации, чем потеряли, +90, на данный момент).

Вы считаете, что на enSO в вашему вопросу отнеслись бы лучше, сделали бы исключение и оставили его открытым? Тогда вам стоит прочитать описание метки [google-adwords на enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-adwords):

> Questions must be about the ADWORDS API ONLY! Questions about accounts or ads are off-topic but may be asked on webmasters.stackexchange.com

Как видите, там прямо капсом написано - разрешены только вопросы по API. Если хотите - попробуйте задать вопрос про просмотр баланса в UI на enSO, и посмотрите, как быстро его удалят :)

Comment: "На сайте есть достаточно жесткий онтопик. Допустимы только вопросы, напряму касающиеся программирования". Да-да, поэтому разрешены вопросы про юр. составляющую и т.п.?

Comment: @Suvitruf "...программирования , администрирования или каких-то **специфических для IT проблем**". Лицензии на ПО - это достаточно специфическая для IT проблема. Остальные вопросы по юридической составляющие - оффтопик. Т.е. да, в вопросе https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2974/ зеленая галка стоит на "Я за то, чтобы переоткрыть все.", но у нас пока онтопик определяется волевым решением администрации, а не зеленой галкой от Саша Черных.

Comment: Юр. вопросы были как пример. Я за все эти годы очень много вопросов наблюдал очень косвенно связанных с IT, но, тем не менее, не закрытых. Вопросы же по adwords (даже, если они не по api), вполне подходят под IT тематику.

Comment: @Suvitruf каким именно образом вопросы по adwords подходят под IT тематику? Это инструмент для маркетинга в чистом виде. Он связан с IT не больше, чем вопросы по Google Photo или заливке видео на Youtube.

Comment: @Suvitruf т.е. вот топикастер не нашел свой баланс в приложении adwords. Это онтопик только засчет того, что он делал это с помощью компьютера? :)

Comment: Не знаю. В моём субъективном мире подходят. В вашем нет, и это нормально.

Comment: Да нет, суть в том, что это частая проблема у людей, как и со многими системами от Google. Поэтому, я этот вопрос в принципе считаю полезным.

Comment: @Suvitruf а еще у людей много проблем с многими другими продуктами от многих других контор. Если у Google есть проблема в интерфейсе, которая мешает их пользователям - стоит обращаться в саппорт гугла. Я уверен, что у пользователей Word / Excel проблем тоже хватает. Но SO ориентирован на разработчиков, а не на конечных пользователей, и это, насколько я знаю, позиция администрации. Нужно уговаривать Николаса, не меня.

Comment: Так я никого не уговариваю, а лишь делюсь мыслями. Ведь так оно работает, да? Здоровый диалог )

Comment: @Suvitruf здоровый диалог предполагает, что все участники диалога следуют правилам и пытаются использовать инструменты сайта для их поддержания (включая соблюдение текущего онтопика). А не голосуют за открытие просто потому что могут :)

Comment: @Suvitruf _Я за все эти годы очень много вопросов наблюдал очень косвенно связанных с IT, но, тем не менее, не закрытых._ И, подозреваю, не оставили голос за закрытие. Возможно, не закрыты они были не потому, что соответствовали правилам, а потому, что сообщество недоработало.

Answer (score 11):

Возможно, SO в чем то и недружелюбен, но вы явно не в том положении, чтобы жаловаться на это. Вы заработали ~50 репы на явном оффтопике, и вопрос с заплюсованным ответом не будет удален духом, даже в закрытом состоянии. Более того, его снова переоткрывают. Вы реально **ничего** не проиграли.

Тем не менее, вы поднимаете несколько интересных вопросов.

> Уберите теги по которым нельзя писать!...

Согласен, метки типа [google-adwords](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-adwords) не нужны. Желательно бы заменить на соответствующие метки с припиской api, чтобы не было неоднозначности относительно того, какие вопросы в них допустимы.

> Сайт просит задавать вопросы, а потом унижают задавших!

Действительно, верно подмечено. Яркие оранжевые баннеры "Не бывает глупых вопросов", при том, что вопросы новичков постоянно ловят минусы и закрываются с левыми причинами, выглядят как-то... неуместно.

Comment: @user "*Очень часто сложные вопросы после выхода новой версии ПО ничего не стоят и некому не нужны*" - Не очень понятно, к чему вы это. Я никоим образом не касаюсь темы сложности вопросов или их устаревания. Проблема вашего вопроса не в этом, а том, что он пограничный: по таким вопросам будут вечные войны открытия/закрытия, пока кто-то не напишет крупными буквами в золотой рамке, что они запрещены (или разрешены).

Comment: наличие ответа не говорит о том, что вопрос нужно переоткрывать. собственно вопрос - зачем переоткрывать ? чтобы завтра "прибежал" кто-нибудь с жалобой "почему мой вопрос закрыли какие-то недружелюбные пользователи ? вон этот вопрос висит открытым, значит и я задал хороший вопрос". Есть ответ - очень хорошо, но от того вопрос не стал онтопиком.

Comment: @Alex я в первый раз нажал на переоткрытие, потому что вопрос был закрыт с явно неправильной причиной. В этот раз я не нажимал.

Comment: Эм. "Согласен, метки типа google-adwords не нужны" - что за чушь?

Comment: @Suvitruf Почему чушь? Если из вопросов по google-adwords только вопросы по API допустимы, почему бы не использовать вместо нее более конкретную метку [google-adwords-api]?

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight ага, давайте ещё переделаем метку [tag:android] на [tag:android-api].

Comment: @Suvitruf причем тут андроид? Речь о метках сервисов для вебмастеров, с которыми возникает неоднозначность. С метками ОС никакой проблемы не существует.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight у меня и с [tag:google-adwords] никаких проблем нет. Ну ок, сервисы: [tag:github], [tag:aws], [tag:google-translate]. С ними всё однозначно?

Comment: @Suvitruf С этими, на первый взгляд да. Видимо с adwords что-то особенное, если из 15 вопросов половина либо закрыты, либо должны быть закрыты.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight для устранения недопонимания добавлено описание к метке [google-adwords](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/google-adwords/info)

Answer (score 7):

> Сайт **StackOverflow на русском** мне показался реально не дружелюбным и не дружественным сайтом. Я сюда пишу все реже и реже.

Это ваше право. Переубеждать вас вряд ли будут. А вот объяснить, почему вы пользуетесь Stack Overflow неправильно (и потому вы встретили некоторое недружелюбие), я попробую.

> Мне здесь закрывают вопросы, которые на англоязычном SO активно и с пользой для всех обсуждаются и люди радуются поиску решения...

Сравнения с "большим SO" ломаются о тот факт, что он на порядок крупнее, и там на каждый вопрос приходится гораздо меньше внимания активистов. Правила у нас в большой степени такие же, даже несколько мягче (у нас не вынесена инспекция кода в отдельное сообщество, нет явного пункта о "рекомендации сторонних ресурсов"), просто соблюдают их у нас строже.

> Задаю по активному (работающему) тегу, существующему на сайте!

Существование метки вообще не является показателем уместности на сайте. Вот прямо сейчас я открыл главную и обнаружил там метку [google-spreadsheet](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-spreadsheet), указывающую на связь вопросов с Google Таблицами. Это не означает, что у нас в тематику вдруг попадают любые вопросы о Google Таблицах.

> Вопрос из реальной практики программиста.

То, что вы программист (?), для этого вопроса скорее случайное обстоятельство. Задавая этот вопрос вы с тем же успехом могли бы быть, скажем, неврологом.

В 2018 году вам не нужно быть программистом, чтобы содержать собственный сайт и использовать на нём AdWords: полно готовых сайтовых движков и подключаемых модулей (плагинов) для них.

И то, о чём вы спрашивали, более глубоких, программистских аспектов инструмента не касается абсолютно никак.

> **Все сделал как рекомендовали**

...и получили оффтопик.

Из этого надо сделать вывод, что вы *изначально* спрашивали то, что здесь в тематику *не входит*. А не то, что рекомендации неправильные и/или на них не обращают внимание.

А **следовало** вам обратиться в поддержку этого инструмента. Что вы, собственно, и сделали.

> **еще хуже стало - стали начислять отрицательные баллы!!!**

Могу только гадать, но скорее всего это из-за перехода из состояния "может быть и уместен, но пока непонятно" в состояние "точно неуместен". Но в таких случаях следует использовать закрывашки, а не минусы. Если человек со своим вопросом адресом ошибся, это не значит, что вопрос плохой. А текст подсказки у "стрелочки вниз", напоминаю, "не отражает стремления разобраться"/"непонятен","не несёт пользы".

Здесь, к сожалению, вообще распространены взгляды, что закрывашки всегда сопровождаются минусами. Настолько, что даже как минимум один из модераторов так считает. Люди иногда такие люди. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

> Закрывают вопросы по одной причине, потом объясняют другую

Это нормально. Просто система на тот момент ещё не пришла в стабильное состояние относительно вашего вопроса. Не спешите.

Закрытие процесс небыстрый, а переоткрытие ещё медленнее. Да, будьте готовы, что после правки вопроса причина закрытия может стать неактуальной и вы быстрее получите совет в комментариях, чем закрытие по новой причине.

> Уберите теги по которым нельзя писать!...

Не успеваем отстреливать, см. [удаление-метки](/questions/tagged/%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b8). Порог для создания меток довольно низкий, процесс никакими дополнительными проверками (кроме небольшого чёрного списка "для крайних случаев") не обременён.

Какие-то метки теряются в зарослях вопросов. Какие-то уже выросли до настолько угрожающих размеров, что их "нельзя просто так взять и" удалить.

> Создается впечатление, что продвинувшиеся заинтересованы принижать начинающих! Хочу верить, что таких мало! )

Продвинувшиеся заинтересованы в соблюдении правил. Начинающим, которые их не соблюдают, на это различными способами указывают. Это "принижение" сколько-нибудь имеет место для нарушителей, может быть. Но не для новичков. Как в случае с "практикой программиста", это случайное обстоятельство.

> Кстати, за то, что я поднял этот вопрос меня реально похвалили в Google (улыбка)

Прекрасно! Значит, задавая вопрос в поддержку Google, вы не ошиблись адресом!

Comment: "не несёт пользы". А какую пользу несёт офтопичный вопрос?

Comment: @alexolut зависит от вопроса. По одной только "оффтопичности" сказать нельзя.

Answer (score 4):

По поводу не дружелюбия возможно вы в чем-то правы, *но это не константа*.
Разные пользователи задают разные вопросы в зависимости от их уровня знаний.
Да, новичку возможно крайне сложно, четко и с первого раза, описать свою проблему или возникший вопрос в процессе разработки, но с другой стороны, вы должны понимать и более опытных пользователей, что слишком сложно выделять уйму времени на разбор *некачественного вопроса*. Ведь все мы где-то работаем и фактически уделяем ресурсу свое личное или рабочее время, а каждый его ценит по-разному.
**Сколько людей - столько мнений и это надо принимать.**
Порой не всем людям хватает терпения (новые пользователи, уж очень часто игнорируют элементарную [справку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help) и порой ленятся прочитать, что они делают не так), от сюда частично и негатив.
*По поводу разницы между основным SO и русскоязычным SO:*
Вы не учитываете небольшую разницу, что у этих сообществ разный возраст и это сообщество в процессе обучения и изменения, оно изучает пользователя и подстраивается под нас. Рано или поздно и тут, возможно будет что-то подобное, поживем увидим.

Comment: Ставлю вам + так как считаю ваш вопрос нормальным, хотя сам буду получать скорее всего минусы. Мнения....

Comment: Хорошо написали. Желание не сразу махать мечём а понять, тоже учусь этому.

Answer (score 1):

Стоит отметить, что оригинальная версия вопроса была мутной. Про это PashaPash правильно ответил.

Ещё забавно:

> Сообщение открыто повторно участником Arhad, 0xdb, MSDN.WhiteKnight,
>   Андрей NOP, avp

и

> Сообщение закрыто по причине «не по теме» участниками Arhad,
>   andreymal, PashaPash♦

Видимо, товарищ Arhad не смог определиться. Но не суть.

Безотносительно вашего вопроса...забавно, что PashaPash ссылкается на онтопик:

> Google AdWords - это инструмент маркетологов, он не имеет никакого
>   отношения ни к программированию, ни к системному администрированию.
>   Вопрос закрыли не потому, что он плохой или неинтересный. Просто он не
>   имеет никакого отношения к онтопику.

Но не закрываются почему-то тогда [такие](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/540586/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%86%D0%B0-%D0%B2-google-play-%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0) вопросы или [такие](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/383937/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B3-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-google-play-%D0%B8-admob/383948)? Они тоже весьма косвенное отношение к разработке имеют.

Comment: В вопросах по ссылкам никакого отношения к разработке. Один стоит закрыть, на второй - повесить историческую блокировку (он был задан еще на hashcode).

Comment: @PashaPash и почему тогда до сих пор не закрыт? Вы ж модератор :)

Comment: @alexolut хочу чтобы community само разобралось с этим вопросом ;)

Comment: @PashaPash а потом придет Qwertiy и переоткроет.

Comment: `Видимо, товарищ Arhad не смог определиться.` — товарищ [думал, что это можно притянуть к онтопичному администрированию](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/43040939#43040939). Но ему [объяснили, что он глубоко ошибался](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/43042080#43042080).

Comment: @PashaPash, зачем блокировать вопрос? На нём и так много плюсов, система его не удалит.

Comment: @Arhad занятно. В смысле, было неплохо, если бы в очереди в описании вопроса на закрытии были б прикреплены логи чата.