# Стоит ли писать ответы на ruSO, когда каждый может их отредактировать?

Tags: обсуждение, правки

Дал ответ на вопрос, тут же пришли и поправили мой ответ. Хорошо бы, если поправили без ошибок, однако пару запятых лишних не убрали.
Я вот задумался над вопросом, а стоит ли писать сюда ответы? Может не стоит? Может этот ресурс создан для тех, кто решает кому и что отвечать? Может этот ресурс для тех, кто считает что их мнение верно, но не другие? Да ежмае, господа, вы своей рецензией убиваете самобытность русского SO. Или перестаньте ставить запятые туда, куда их не поставил автор. Он так видит. Спасибо.

Comment: Я так понимаю, про это идет речь? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/867425/revisions

Comment: У `SOF RU` такая вот философия. Иногда хотят как лучше - получается хуже. не стоит на это обращать внимания. Откатить правку всегда можно. Минус только в том, что человек может кардинально изменить ваш ответ, а вы это не заметите.

Comment: Очевидно что про это. Более того, только цензор знает о чем речь. Еще более того - цензор сейчас начнет рассказывать о своем представлении сообщений, а так же цензор обычно не видит в этом проблемы.

Comment: Начнем с того, что подобного рода вещи неуместны в рамках ruSO. Если бы Вы подправили тон своего сообщения, то, возможно, на ruSO Meta Вы могли бы пожаловаться на то, что Вас не устраивает. Лично я и вовсе не вижу проблемы в том, что Ваш ответ **многократно улучшили**, совершенно не поменяв его сути

Comment: @Kir_Antipov многократно улучшили ? Вы серьезно ? Во сколько крат ? Расскажите мне об этом подробнее :)))

Comment: Лично мне (как и большинству людей) куда приятнее знакомиться с постом, код в котором не уехал на мой второй монитор, а аккуратно отформатирован; а также грамматика и пунктуация которого сохраняется хотя бы на уровне средней школы. После правки [@Let's say Pie](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/300000/lets-say-pie) число ошибок, снижающих читаемость Вашего текста, резко снизилось. Пост до сих пор содержит помарки, но уже в более разумных количествах

Comment: @Kir_Antipov расскажите об этих ошибках пожалуйста. Вы говорите именно о коде или о замене слов и запятых ?  И почему пост до сих пор содержит помарки после "исправлений" ? Тут знаете как бывает. Либо трусы надеть либо крест снимать.

Comment: @Kir_Antipov вы опять серьезно ? Все что может быть критикой вами воспринимается как агрессия ? У меня для вас печальные новости... знаете ли.

Comment: @zalex вы свой вопрос перечитайте. Я вижу там и агрессию, и оскорбления.

Comment: Я еще раз настоятельно прошу Вас сменить тон беседы на более дружественный. Отпускаемые Вами "афоризмы" [неуместны в контексте уважительной беседы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/conduct). Критика (как и вообще любое высказывание) может носить разный тон. Я вижу в Вашей критике агрессию и нападки на сообщество и администрацию

Comment: По поводу ошибок: у Вас неверно отформатирован код, а также полностью отсутствуют обособления вводных слов, (дее-)причастных оборотов и прочих конструкций. Для читающего и следящего за речью человека такой текст объективно **очень сложен** для восприятия. Так что мысль, которую Вы хотели донести своим ответом, будет утеряна. Сообщество в лице вышеуказанного [участника](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/300000/lets-say-pie) попыталось не допустить этого, в результате чего нарвалось на необоснованную агрессию

Comment: @Kir_Antipov к сожалению я, читая правила, не увидел ограничений по поводу форматирования кода. Так же не заметил пункта про "обособления вводных слов". Более того, я вполне себе уверен что любой человек, владеющий языком Достоевского весьма себе бы понял то, что я пишу. Однако, видимо, вводное слово тут, не все читают :)

Comment: @zalex ограничений как раз и нет. Дело именно в том, что ruSO (как и любой другой проект в рамках SE) - база знаний. Как часто Вы встречаете в книгах/статьях по программированию ошибки в тексте? Или некрасиво отформатированный код? Согласен, иногда это попадается, все мы бываем невнимательны. Именно для этого и нужно сообщество, которое поможет Вам облачить Ваши знания в более читабельную и удобную для восприятия форму для будущих поколений

Comment: Даже ваш юрист пришел и обнулил часть сообщений. Вы смешны.

Comment: @zalex что Вы имеете в виду под данными словами? Ваш вопрос, все комментарии и Ваш ответ полностью мигрировали на Мету. И к кому Вы обращаетесь?

Comment: @Kir_Antipov я понял практически все, вот только не очень понял почему вместо -5  вижу -1  данному посту ? Кто то отозвал свои голоса против ?

Comment: @zalex при переносе на мету голоса сбрасываются системой автоматически.

Comment: Вы зря удалили запятую после "многократно" :)

Comment: @PashaPash да я вообще зря написал на этот ресурс.

Comment: @zalex в чем вообще суть ваших претензий? Человек пришел, исправил в вашем вопросе форматирование кода и исправил ошибки в тексте. Бесплатно. Он не получил за это ни репутации, ни денег, ничего. Чем вы недовольны?

Comment: @PashaPash написал ответ.

Comment: @zalex ваш "ответ" - это просто набор обвиниений всех сразу непонятно в чем. Вы можете прямо сформулировать проблему, которую видите (или чувствуете)? Участник помог вам с оформлением ответа. Не удалял, не закрывал, не минусовал. Почему вы приняли это за оскорбление и за проявление ненависти лично к вам? Какого поведения вы бы ожидали и почему?

Comment: Очень часто некоторые участники начинаю редактировать в вопросе или ответе, исключительно, грамматические ошибки. Иногда обоснованно, а иногда доходит до вот таких нелепостей, когда не выделен деепричастный оборот или буква не так написана. Как по мне тут одна причина - заработать очередной значок (дается за редактирование опр. кол-ва вопросов или ответов). Не раз с таким сталкивалась и, действительно, очень раздражает ... НО нужно успокоиться, понять и простить))) Больше позитива. Потому как такие исправления тоже имеют место быть. Ведь вопрос или ответ мы даем не только для себя, а для всех!

Comment: + как уже писали выше, Вы всегда можете откатить редактирование до своей прежней версии.

Comment: *самобытность* по вашему заключается в том что бы писать как душе угодно? Ваш ответ отредактировали(на мой взгляд, данное редактирование вполне уместно), ответ стал *лучше*  (легче читается), основной посыл не изменился, откуда такая агрессия? чем конкретно Вы не довольны, о каких ошибках старших идет речь? может добавите чуть *конструктива*, глядишь и минуса уйдут

Comment: А вы ведь сами не умеете ставить запятые правильно :)

Comment: @andreymal вам не удалось понять мой посыл ? Речь не о запятых ведь. Совсем не о запятых.

Comment: @zalex Поправил название вопроса на соответствующее тексту вопроса. Если вы не согласны - попробуйте дать другое, соответствующее, название

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight не дубликат. Тут просто нытьё против правок вовсе. Там — об контроле правок.

Comment: @alexolut иногда у меня возникает ощущение благодаря ресурсу вы думать совершенно разучились. Не идет речь о нытье из за правок, речь идет о том, что придет человек который в силу возможности подсказать, но тут набегает очередь "правильных" и каждое его сообщение делают "правильным". Ну неужели не доходит ? Стоит еще разжевать ? Вы же прям как секта, зубами уцепившись за линию партии. Думайте чуточку ширше или ширее :))) Обязательно поправьте этот мой комментарий мол: правильно "шире"! И громко при этом тыцнуть в Enter.

Comment: @zalex комментарии править только модераторы могут, так что тут Вы ошиблись. И Вы бы, наверное, могли что-то разжевать, но это не тот случай.

Comment: @alexolut любезный. Если вы прочитаете мой вопрос и мой ответ, который по - сути расширяет мой вопрос, вы бы поняли о чем я вообще речь веду. 
Знаете почему русскоязычные ресурсы обычно ущербны ? Не знаете. потому что наверняка считаете что это не так. Но у меня для вас есть плохие новости. 
Однако я зачастил. Прошу меня простить за это.

Answer (score 9):

Этот ресурс для тех, кто умеет слушать других и умеет признавать свои ошибки.

И именно поэтому вам не стоит здесь отвечать. Потому что именно вы и являетесь тем, кто считает, что его мнение единственно верное. Если бы вы допускали, что хоть иногда ошибаетесь, вы бы не обижались на правку, которая в целом улучшает ваш ответ.

Если же вы почему-то решите остаться, то вам нужно будет осознать, что редактирование чужих сообщений - это не чья-то прихоть, а часть модели сайта. Ознакомиться с ней можно здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/stackexchange, особенно я хотел бы обратить ваше внимание на раздел [Почему кто-то может редактировать мои сообщения? Как работает система редактирования?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/editing)

Comment: `И именно поэтому вам не стоит здесь отвечать.`
Вы действительно не понимаете о чем я пишу ? Ощущение что у вас на глазах шоры и вы не можете понять о чем речь. Речь то именно об этом. Вы прям сейчас решаете, стоит мне отвечать или не стоит. 
Более того, мое сообщение вы читаете через призму своего понимания концепции и данных вам полномочий.
Я согласен с правилами, однако я не согласен с тем, что стоит ими злоупотреблять. Всего то. Это ведь легко понять. Не сложно. Вообще просто.

Comment: Это ресурс для вопросов и ответов, а не форум психологов. 
Однако есть ощущение что не только я почувствовал расхождение с идеей ресурса и его исполнением. 
[раз](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6928/%D0%9E-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%80%D1%83c%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-stackoverflow?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[два](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4770/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82-stack-overflow?rq=1)

Comment: @zalex по вашим ссылкам нет ваших единомышленников. Никто из отписавшихся там не обижался на мелкие исправления в своих сообщениях. Кстати, обратите внимание что там почему-то на вопросах и ответах куча плюсов, в отличии от вашего.

Comment: Разве речь идет об обиде ? Я был бы рад чтоб вы чуточку шире мыслили.Спасибо за комментарий. \

Comment: @zalex на этот раз вы попали в правильное сообщение - там ваш единомышленник. Все остальное - ваши домыслы.

Comment: @zalex совершенно верно, вы напрасно все это затеяли. Правка чужих сообщений - это один из ключевых моментов SO, которые и сделали SO тем чем он является. Если вам не нравится этот момент - вам следует выбрать [другой сайт](https://toster.ru/).

Comment: нет, уважаемый. Тут вы совершаете основополагающую ошибку, до которой вы все ни как не можете дойти своим пониманием происходящего. Не вы или кто то другой не можете мне рекомендовать что мне следует делать. Разве не очевидно что именно этот момент вызвал претензии ? Сколько еще раз нужно написать чтоб вы хотя бы чуточку спустились с небес и поняли что беспокоит множество людей, которые хотят вносить лепту в общее дело? Вы поймите что считая себя единственно верным мнением - вы не добьетесь результата.На секунду просто представьте что я имею право на свое мнение и тогда возможно до вас дойдет.

Comment: @zalex безусловно у вас есть право на свое мнение. Но у сайта есть правила и модель, которые обязательны для выполнения. Если ваше мнение не совместимо с правилами сайта - вам не следует на этом сайте ничего писать, вот и все.

Comment: Я говорю о том что когда у пользователя есть какие то сомнения, то вменяемая администрация эти сомнения развеивает, однако вы выбрали позицию "самдурак".  Я еще раз призываю вас обдумать, а не писать по-шаблону. Вы действительно не видите свою проблему? Вы действительно считаете что все кто с вами, тот против вас ? 
Я прошу прощения если кого то обидел, я сделал это намеренно и так же откровенно прошу за это прощения. Однако я хотел бы донести до вас всех мысль, что любое мнение отличное от вашего или даже от правил - стоит того чтобы задуматься, а не пытаться сразу загнобить неугодного.

Comment: @zalex почему вы считаете что мнений подобных вашему никогда не высказывалось?

Comment: Где вы из моих написанных слов увидели что я считаю что мнение подобное моему не высказывалось ? Вы придумали это ? Я даже ссылки выкладывал. Пожалуйста, перестаньте.

Comment: @Rootware ну, на en.SO я наблюдал ту же самую проблему, так что вам просто не повезло. Но скажите, какое отношение эта проблема имеет к редактированию вопросов и ответов?

Comment: @PavelMayorov абсолютно никакого. Смысл этой темы поболтать обо всём наболевшем. Вот я и вставил свои 5 копеек в балаган.

Comment: @Rootware почему вы так решили? Кажется, вы перепутали этот вопрос вот с этим: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7567/178779

Answer (score -8):

Тут же я решил спросить у гугла, а он мне в ответ выдал что на духу
https://www.quora.com/Why-do-some-people-hate-Stack-Overflow

И вот прям точь-в-точь. И даже эти прекрасные минусики ставят те самые цензоры. 
Но что еще забавнее, что цензоры не читают и не учатся ничему. Они лишь считают себя правыми.

Господа. Вам всем нужно унять свою мнимую значимость в обществе и плясать от того, что мы все сидим в одной лодке. Иначе все закончится как всегда.  :)

Comment: Полностью поддерживаю Вас zalex. Правка вопросов и ответов недопустима. Никто не может влезть в голову человека и понять, что человек хотел спросить/ответить. Никакие ссылки на исправления грамматики/пунктуации не могут быть признаны как причина правки. Если кому-то не понятно что хотел спросить автор, то он может просто не отвечать на вопрос.

Comment: @pepsicoca1, не готов с вами согласиться) Зачастую только попытка влезть в чужую голову с целью выяснения что именно хотел сказать человек и позволяет его понять и ему помочь. Например, если человек не очень хорошо владеет языком или затрудняется выразить свою мысль из-за незнания специальных терминов. Ну а грамматические и прочие ошибки править не может быть плохо - всё таки мы в первую очередь не самопиаримся тут в ответах/вопросах помогая конкретному ТС, а создаём общедоступную БД знаний. А она должна быть как можно более комфортна для потребления. Правильная речь в этом случае очень важна)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, правильная речь, кто решает что есть правильная речь? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/861293/revisions я так понимаю. без вашей правки ответ бы удалили, тем не менее в результате правки .. ну вы поняли

Comment: @qwabra, если честно, то не очень понял что вы хотите сказать)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Совершенно с Вами не согласен. Как экстремальный пример - если бы Эйнштейн в 1905 году опубликовал на SO свою теорию относительности (Коллеги, как Вы думаете, если бы скорость света была константой, то тогда все явления легко объясняются сжатием Лоренца и ...), то ее бы отредактировали так, чтобы все понятия были понятны в рамках старой теории эфира. И суть была бы уничтожена.

Comment: @pepsicoca1 ну мы же с вами знаем кто на самом деле автор теории относительности, правда ?

Comment: @pepsicoca1, Эйнштейн бы не пошёл на SO писать оффтопик, я думаю... И если б у него только орфографию поправили, то суть бы не изменилась. Но это про ваш пример. А вот на SO вопросы про программирование и тут очень сложно придумать пример вопроса/ответа который бы был о принципиально новом осмыслении какой-то очень сложной теории. Обычно тут про то как и какой метод вызвать. В таких случаях сложно так изменить ответ что из него суть пропадёт) Т.е. я не считаю вашу аналогию корректной по отношению к нашему сайту.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб [В таких случаях сложно так изменить ответ что из него суть пропадёт] Опять же совершенно с Вами не согласен. Хрестоматийный пример "казнить нельзя помиловать". Даже добавление всего лишь запятой в разные места этого предложения кардинально меняет смысл. А на сайте SO непрошеные редакторы далеко не ограничиваются добавлениями запятых.

Comment: @zalex [ну мы же с вами знаем кто на самом деле автор теории относительности, правда ?] Кто бы он ни был, на сайте SO ему бы не поздоровилось. Редакторы заредактировали бы его текст насмерть. Кстати, хороший пример. На сайтах, публикующих научные статьи тоже есть редактирование. Но всегда правка посылается на согласование автору и без его визы текст не публикуется.